# bash sed: -e expression #1, char 21: number option to `s' command may not be zero

Tags: bash, sed

I want to rewrite a line in a conf file. The text that should be put on line 88 is: auth 0.0.0.0/0 - -
 My command is :

```
sed -i '88s/.*/auth 0.0.0.0/0 - -/' /etc/opt/ss5/ss5.conf
```

But I'm getting an error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: number option to `s' command may not be zero
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the text you try to inject contains `/` which is used by sed as a separator.
You need either to escape this slash , or to use a different sed separator. Sed can accept any character as separator, i.e #.

```
sed -i '88s/.*/auth 0.0.0.0\/0 - -/' /etc/opt/ss5/ss5.conf
#OR
sed -i '88s#.*#auth 0.0.0.0/0 - -#' /etc/opt/ss5/ss5.conf
```